How do I install the nltk library's "averaged_perceptron_tagger" on railway server?
Hi I am building an API with django REST Framework for generating a PowerPoint slide using python pptx package. I'm also using NLTK(Natural Language Toolkit) library to process text by tokenizing and tagging the tokens, it then returns the noun and determiner if they are present in the text. It also checks if the text tokens are >= 50 characters. If they are, it splits the text from where the word Slide occurs returns the noun and determiner as a value in a dictionary with the key being title. When I make a post request to the API endpoint, I got this error while testing on Postman:
{
    "error":"\n**********************************************************************\n  Resource [93maveraged_perceptron_tagger[0m not found.\n  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:\n\n  [31m>>> import nltk\n  >>> nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')\n  [0m\n  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html\n\n  Attempted to load [93mtaggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/averaged_perceptron_tagger.pickle[0m\n\n  Searched in:\n    - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\eugen/nltk_data'\n    - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\eugen\\\\Documents\\\\backend\\\\Authentication\\\\venv\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\eugen\\\\Documents\\\\backend\\\\Authentication\\\\venv\\\\share\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\eugen\\\\Documents\\\\backend\\\\Authentication\\\\venv\\\\lib\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\eugen\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'C:\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'D:\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'E:\\\\nltk_data'\n**********************************************************************\n"
}

I believe  the error is due to the fact that the nltk package and it's other dependencies are installed in my virtual environment not on the railway server directly, because when I tested the endpoint while running the server locally it worked perfectly, so my question is: how do I install the NLTK's averaged_perceptron_tagger on railway?
I have downloaded the nltk package locally and also created a folder named nltk_data in the root of my project's directory and I copied the taggers and tokenizers files into the folder I created in my project and committed the changes:
I also specified the NLTK data path like this:
# Setting the NLTK data path
nltk.data.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'nltk_data'))

Here's the folder structure:
my_project/
├── nltk_data/
│   ├── taggers/
│   │   └── averaged_perceptron_tagger
│   ├── tokenizers/
│   │   └── punkt
├── my_app/
├── manage.py
├── ...

Here's my views.py:
import os
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from drf_spectacular.types import OpenApiTypes
from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema
from pptx import Presentation
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import pos_tag
from nltk.data import find
from nltk import download
from nltk.tokenize import blankline_tokenize
from .models import PresentationData
from .serializers import PresentationDataSerializer
from openai import OpenAI

# Setting the NLTK data path
nltk.data.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'nltk_data'))

OpenAI.api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
client = OpenAI()


class GenerateZlideView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def _extract_first_noun_determiner(self, text):
        tokens = word_tokenize(text)
        tagged = pos_tag(tokens)

        noun = determiner = None
        for word, tag in tagged:
            if not noun and tag.startswith('NN'): # Noun
                noun = word
            if not determiner and tag.startswith('DT'): # Determiner
                determiner = word
            if noun and determiner:
                break
        return noun, determiner

    def _generate_presentation(self, user_input, request):
        user_input = request.data.get('text')
        # Tokenizing the user input 
        text_tokens = word_tokenize(user_input)


        if len(text_tokens) >= 50:
            # Splitting the user input into slides based on "Slide" keyword
            slides = user_input.split("Slide")
            zlide = []

            for idx, slide in enumerate(slides):
                if slide.strip(): # Ignoring strings
                    try:
                        title, content = slide.split(":", 1)
                        title = title.strip()
                        content = content.strip()

                        # Extracting first noun and determiner from the content
                        noun, determiner = self._extract_first_noun_determiner(content)

                        # Creating title from the first noun and determiner
                        title = " ".join(filter(None, [determiner, noun])).title()

                        if noun and determiner:`your text`
                            title = f"{determiner} {noun}"
                        elif noun:`your text`

                            title = noun
                        elif determiner:
                            title = determiner

                        # Creating a JSON object for the slide
                        zlide_json = {
                            "slide": idx,
                            "title": title,
                            "content": content
                        }

                        # Append JSON object to the list
                        zlide.append(zlide_json)
                    except ValueError:
                        continue # Handle any case where the split fails
                        zlide_json_output = json.dumps(zlide, indent=4)
                return json.loads(zlide_json_output)
                # Return the list of JSON objects
            else:
                # prompt = query_json.replace("{{QUERY}}", user_input)
                prompt = f"Generate a 5 slide content for a powerpoint presentation with    slides, titles and content and convert them into a JSON array with each item having a slide, title,  content about: {user_input}"
                completion = client.chat.completions.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=  [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}])

                response = completion.choices[0].message.content

                return json.loads(response)

    def _save_presentation_to_db(self, presentation_data, request):
        presentation_title = request.data.get("title", "Presentation Title")
        presentation_data = PresentationData.objects.create(title=presentation_title,     json_data=presentation_data)
        return presentation_data

    @extend_schema(
        operation_id="Generate Zlide Endpoint",
        description="This endpoint does the actual slide generation",
        summary="This endpoint will generate a slide based on user input by making a call to     the OpenAI API and then return the data in JSON format",
        request=OpenApiTypes.OBJECT,
        responses={200: PresentationDataSerializer},
    )
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            user_input = request.data.get("user_input")
            input_text = request.data.get("input_text")
            request.data['user_input'] = user_input
            presentation_data = self._generate_presentation(input_text, request)
            presentation_data = self._save_presentation_to_db(presentation_data, request)
            serializer = PresentationDataSerializer(presentation_data)
            return Response({'message': ''})

            # If not isinstance(presentation_data, dict):
            # return Response({"error": "Invalid response from OpenAI"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            presentation_data = self._save_presentation_to_db(presentation_data, request)
            serializer = PresentationDataSerializer(presentation_data)
            return Response({'message': 'Presentation data saved successfully.',   'presentation_id': presentation_data.id, 'slide_data':json.loads(serializer.data["json_data"])}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

So my question is: How do I install the averaged_perceptron_tagger on the railway server? Is there any other way to resolve the error?
Here's a screenshot of my views.py
I made a post request to the API endpoint (https://zlide.up.railway.app/zlide/generatezlide/) with this JSON data as the body:
{
    "text":"Slide 1: Introduction Brief Introduction to RoboTech Innovations Mission Statement: 'Empowering Industries with Cutting-Edge Robotics Solutions' Slide 2: The Problem Identify the key pain points or challenges in industries that can be addressed by robotics technology Statistics or data illustrating the market need for robotics solutions Slide 3: Our Solution Overview of RoboTech's innovative robotics solutions Highlight key features and benefits How our technology addresses the identified problems Slide 4: Product Portfolio Showcase the range of robotics products offered by RoboTech Include images, names, and brief descriptions of each product Highlight versatility and adaptability across industries Slide 5: Market Opportunity Market size and potential for robotics technology Target industries and segments Growth projections and trends in the robotics industry"
}

This is the response that I expected:
{
    "message": "Presentation data saved successfully.",
    "presentation_id": 12,
    "slide_data": [
        {
            "slide": 1,
            "title": "Introduction",
            "content": "Introduction to RoboTech Innovations Mission Statement: 'Empowering   Industries with Cutting-Edge Robotics Solutions."
        },
        {
            "slide": 2,
            "title": "The Problem",
            "content": "The Problem Identify the key pain points or challenges in industries   that can be addressed by robotics technology Statistics or data illustrating the market need for robotics solutions."
        },
        {
            "slide": 3,
            "title": "Our Solution",
            "content": "Overview of RoboTech's innovative robotics solutions Highlight key  features and benefits How our technology addresses the identified problems."
        },
        {
            "slide": 4,
            "title": "Product",
            "content": "Product Portfolio Showcase the range of robotics products offered by   RoboTech Include images, names, and brief descriptions of each product Highlight versatility and adaptability across industries."
        },
        {
            "slide": 5,
            "title": "Market",
            "content": "Market size and potential for robotics technology Target industries and   segments Growth projections and trends in the robotics industry."
        }
    ]
}

Unfortunately this is the response I got:
    {
        "error":"\n**********************************************************************\n       Resource [93maveraged_perceptron_tagger[0m not found.\n  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:\n\n  [31m>>> import nltk\n  >>> nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')\n  [0m\n  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html\n\n  Attempted to load [93mtaggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/averaged_perceptron_tagger.pickle[0m\n\n  Searched in:\n    - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\eugen/nltk_data'\n    - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\eugen\\\\Documents\\\\backend\\\\Authentication\\\\venv\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\eugen\\\\Documents\\\\backend\\\\Authentication\\\\venv\\\\share\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\eugen\\\\Documents\\\\backend\\\\Authentication\\\\venv\\\\lib\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\eugen\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'C:\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'D:\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'E:\\\\nltk_data'\n**********************************************************************\n"
    }


The way the error message suggest should work. First import nltk, then nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger').
